# How do I run a static method on a CFC without using cfinvoke?

Tags: coldfusion, cfc

How do I invoke a static method on a CFC without using cfinvoke? I know that I can do this:

```
<cfinvoke component="MyComponent" method="myStaticMethod' arg1="blah" returnvariable=myReturnVar>
```

I would like to be able to invoke this method the same way I would a UDF:

```
<cfset myReturnVar = MyComponent.myStaticMethod(blah)>
```

This, however, does not work. Is there syntax that I am messing up or is this just not possible?

Comment: This is not a direct answer to your question but you could do something close with mixins, just put the method you want to act like a static method in its own file so you can call it stand alone then CFINCLUDE that file in your CFC. There are some caching implications with CFINCLUDE but it is worth thinking about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

not possible, since there's no "static method" in ColdFusion.

The `<cfinvoke>` line in your question is the same as:

```
myReturnVar = CreateObject("component", "MyComponent").myStaticMethod(arg1="blah");
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought that might be the case but wasn't sure.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that if you were using CreateObject to make a JAVA object then you would do the same thing as here....you have to make a static reference to the class (by NOT calling init)....before calling the static method.

Comment: Also, you should prefer this over <cfinvoke> because it's more efficient for CF internally even though that may seem counter intuitive.

Comment: @Bialecki really? why is it more efficient?

Comment: @Henry somewhere in the CF documentation they mention that creating a component and calling a method on it is more efficient than <cfinvoke>.  Very odd, I know, but it was a bug in CF 7, don't know if it was fixed in 8 or 9.  I'll poke around for a link to it.

Comment: If you find it, I would be interested in reading about it too. The only performance recommendation I was aware of regarded reuse. ie It is more efficient to create once, and reuse an object multiple times, rather than creating a new object each time ie Calling <cfinvoke component="MyComponent" method="..."> over and over.

Answer (score 3):

You need to create the object first.

```
<cfset MyComponent = createObject("component","MyComponent") />
<cfset myReturnVar = MyComponent.myMethod(blah) />
```

Comment: This is the same as what Henry wrote, not sure why it was downvoted

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a really old post but here's an updated answer for more modern CF/Lucee supporting static constructs for anyone who might stumble across this like I did :-)

based off of:
https://modern-cfml.ortusbooks.com/cfml-language/components/static-

```
component MyComponent{
   
    static {
        appendToArgValue : "text"
    }
    
    
    public static function myStaticMethod( arg1 ){
        return arg1 & static.appendToArgValue;
    };

}

MyComponent::myStaticMethod("blah")
```

Lucee documentation: https://docs.lucee.org/guides/lucee-5/component-static.html